# Serverless Framework AWS deployment

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to use the serverless framework to deploy a lambda function to AWS but run into this error when running `serverless deploy --verbose`

```
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Creating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack create progress...
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - hello-world-dev
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::S3::Bucket - ServerlessDeploymentBucket
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - hello-world-dev
Serverless: Stack create finished...
 
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  Stack 'hello-world-dev' does not exist
```

This is the first time deploying it.

I have setup the region in the .yml file and have permissions on AWS, is there a way to change what S3 bucket that the deployment uses and point to an existing one? I think that could be one of the issues.

Comment: this is a first time for deployment ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan yes first time deploying it.

Comment: can you go to cloudformation AWS and check which service did it error there ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan in AWS cloudformation shows that it has successfully deleted and the reason is I have reached my bucket limit. Is there a way to point this to an existing bucket?

Comment: you can go to s3 bucket and look for any s3 bucket there ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan yeah I can check the s3 buckets however the maximum limit has been reached so when deploying I want to know if there is an option to select an existing one instead of creating a new one?

Comment: what's maximum limit ? you can use `serverless deploy --force`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can provide a custom bucket for serverless using the plugin. Go through this link [use custom bucket in serverless](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-deployment-bucket)

**Edit:**
You can now directly specify deployment bucket in serverless without any plugin.
Refer: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml#deployment-bucket